# Fitting a log-normal function on array values using Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, distribution

I am trying to fit log-normal pdf on the matrix generated using the inbuilt log-normal function but it doesn't fit. I was wondering why it is off. The plot is attached for reference.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mu, sigma = 0.2, 0.5 # mean and standard deviation
A=np.random.lognormal(mean=0.2, sigma=0.5, size=(10, 10))

count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(A, 100, density=True, align='mid')
x = np.linspace(min(bins), max(bins), 10000)

pdf = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))/ (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))
plt.plot(x, pdf, linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't fit? Try changing the size of your `A` array to something like 10000 (`size=10000`) and you'll see a good fit

Comment: But I don't wish to increase the size of the array. I wish to keep it 10x10.

Comment: Ok. What do you expect (or want) to see?

Comment: I just want to check whether the pdf fits the data i.e. 10x10 matrix using the same mu, sigma.

Comment: That was my point though that with 10 entries in 10 histograms it is going to be hard (impossible) to tell. Maybe someone else has a better suggestion.

Comment: You could try `plt.hist(A.ravel(), 10, ...)` to obtain a histogram that makes a bit more sense.  You really need quite less bins than samples.  Also, having only 100 samples is quite low for what you are trying.

Comment: Did you look into seaborn? E.g. `ax=sns.histplot(A.ravel(), kde=True)`